# Regular expression for 1 number and 3 capital letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I havent looked much into regexp, but i know that numbers are `[0-9]` and capital letters are `[A-Z]`.

What i would like to know is: How to filter out certain words from a string that matches the regexp, and style them. For example:

```
string s = 'Hello ABC1 world C2DF !';
//magic code here
//result:
'Hello <b>ABC1</b> world <b>C2DF</b> !'
```

Comment: What words are you trying to filter out? Do they have some specific format?

Comment: @Lorax The length is always 4 characters, where 1 of them is a number. And its only capital letters. The number can be at any of the positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this you definitely need [**word boundaries**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). The other solution will match also e.g. on "1ABCD" and highlight you the first four characters.

My solution involves a [look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but if you don't want this just take the word boundaries `\b` to your own solution.

```
\b(?=[^\d]*\d[^\d]*)[A-Z\d]{4}\b
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32taa)

I match the 4 character word with `[A-Z\d]{4}` the word boundaries `\b` around, ensure that there is no other letter or digit before or ahead. The positive lookahead `(?=[^\d]*\d[^\d]*)` ensure that your requirement of exactly one digit is met.

Comment: I'm accepthing this instead, since its the most correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This one should match your needs:

```
/[0-9][A-Z]{3}|[A-Z][0-9][A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{2}[0-9][A-Z]|[A-Z]{3}[0-9]/
```

This matches (and matches only):

```
0ABC
A0BC
AB0C
ABC0
```

Of course, in the above list, `A`, `B` and `C` could be any capital char, and `0` could be any digit.

Comment: Followup question: Shouldnt /[0-9](9)/ filter out a number with 9 digits? 123456789 for example?

Comment: @Johan No, cardinality must be specified using brackets, i.e. `/[0-9]{9}/` in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex :

```
/\b(\d[A-Z]{3}|[A-Z]\d[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{2}\d[A-Z]|[A-Z]{3}\d)\b/
```

With [replace method in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) :

```
s.replace(/\b(\d[A-Z]{3}|[A-Z]\d[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{2}\d[A-Z]|[A-Z]{3}\d)\b/g,"<b>$&</b>");
```

Tested script :

```
var output,
    text    = "9GHJ is saying hello to ABC1 world C2DF, but 89UI is showing up with his friend HUIP, nothing to do, they are not welcome ! As garyh said, these NUMB3RZ should not be replaced",
    regex   = /\b(\d[A-Z]{3}|[A-Z]\d[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{2}\d[A-Z]|[A-Z]{3}\d)\b/g,
    replace = "<b>$&</b>";

output = text.replace(regex,replace)

console.log ( output );
```

Will output this :

```
<b>9GHJ</b> is saying hello to <b>ABC1</b> world <b>C2DF</b>, but 89UI is showing up with his friend HUIP, nothing to do, they are not welcome ! As garyh said, these NUMB3RZ should not be replaced
```

Comment: It seems to be matching all 4 letters words even if the numer is not present.

Comment: Followup question: Shouldnt `/[0-9](9)/` filter out a number with 9 digits? `123456789` for example?

Comment: You should add `\b` to the beginning and end of the regex to avoid capturing part of the text in strings like `2AGS2` `AB2SS` `2A2AGS2`

Comment: @Johan you probably meant `/[0-9]{9}/`